# Why getting the specified value "Result" cannot be parsed, or is out of range?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, use-effect, use-state, react-component

I have a Critical Angle calculator as a ReactJs Component. But I am getting this warning upon clicking on the Calculate button: `The specified value "Result" cannot be parsed or is out of range.` Can someone point out the error?The code for the Component is mentioned below:

```
 const CriticalAngle = () => {
    const [n1, setN1] = useState(null);
    const [n2, setN2] = useState(null);
    const [result, setResult] = useState(null);
    const calcResult=()=>{
      setResult(57.29578*Math.asin(n2/n1));
    }
    
    return (
      <>
        <Form>
          <Form.Group className="mb-4">
            <Form.Label>Refractive Index of Incident Medium(Denser Medium)</Form.Label>
            <Form.Control
              type="number"
              placeholder="Enter the value of n1"
              onChange={(e) => setN1(Number(e.target.value))}
              value={n1 === null ? "" : n1}
            />
          </Form.Group>
          <Form.Group className="mb-4">
            <Form.Label>Refractive Index of Refractive Medium(Rarer Medium)</Form.Label>
            <Form.Control
              type="number"
              placeholder="Enter the value of n2"
              onChange={(e) => setN2(Number(e.target.value))}
              value={n2 === null ? "" : n2}
            />
          </Form.Group>
          <Form.Group className="mb-4">
            <Form.Label>Critical Angle</Form.Label>
            <Form.Control
              type="number"
              disabled="true"
              value={result === null ? "Result" : result}
            />
          </Form.Group>
        </Form>
        <div className="button-custom-grp">
          <Button variant="primary" onClick={calcResult}>
            Calculate
          </Button>

       
        </div>
      </>
    )
  }
```

Comment: not sure at all, but I'd bet on the unexpected "Result" string to be assigned to the value of a control targeted as "number". You should use the condition to create two different fragments instead of reusing the same.

Comment: can you explain please , I couldnt get you @MarioVernari

Answer (score 0):

Well, I don't know what those tags are, but here is my guess...

The critical angle's control is marked as `type="number"`, hence it doesn't like values which are not numeric, like the string "Result" is.

Instead, you could try something like this. I used a `Form.Label` tag to wrap the "Result" string, but I think there's something better.

```
      <Form.Group className="mb-4">
        <Form.Label>Critical Angle</Form.Label>
        {result === null
           ? (
             <Form.Label>Result</Form.Label>
           ) : (
             <Form.Control
                type="number"
                disabled="true"
                value={result === null ? "Result" : result}
             />
           )
        }
      </Form.Group>
```

I can't help more than this.